# Changing shape "Line" Begin/End after creation

Tags: excel, vba, line

all!

I am creating a Line with

```
Private Const Origin_X = 248.4
Private Const Origin_Y = 248.4

Private Const Width_X = 205.2
Private Const Height_Y = 205.2

[ ... ]

    Dim sh As Shape

    X1 = Origin_X
    Y1 = Origin_Y

    X2 = Origin_X + Width_X
    Y2 = Origin_Y + Height_Y

    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
    sh.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
```

This line points from its origin to some lower right point.

Now I want it to point to some upper left point. But I can't figure out what to do. Obviously the .Width and .Height properties don't allow negative values. I've read something about .Nodes and .Points, but can't get them to collaborate.

The lines

```
X1 = Origin_X
Y1 = Origin_Y

X2 = Origin_X - Width_X
Y2 = Origin_Y - Height_Y

Set nd = sh.Nodes(1)

nd.Points(1, 2) = Y1
nd.Points(1, 2) = Y1

nd.Points(2, 1) = X2
nd.Points(2, 2) = Y2
```

produce an "index out of range" error message when trying to assign nd. The sh.Nodes list seems to be empty, sh.Nodes.Count is 0.

Thanks for any help.

Michael

edit: It wasn't obvious, but: Just flipping or rotating won't help. I need a method to change the line pointing from a fixed origin dynamically to anywhere, in any direction / length. I might have x2/y2 or as an alternative I might have a/r (alpha and radius) or whatever.

Right now I create a new Line and delete the old one then. But this causes flicker and maybe memory problems, too.

Comment: You can use `Top`, `Left`, `Width` and `Height` to adjust the size, and `Flip` to adjust the slope.

Answer (score 0):

line has its beginning and its end, so swapping them will do

```
Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(X2, Y2, X1, Y1)
sh.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadTriangle
```